# windows cmd .bat handle file names with space

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filenames, space

I have a windows cmd .bat file that change the encoding of many .csv files as follows:

```
for /R %%f in (.\*) do (
    if %%~xf == .csv (
        powershell -Command "get-content -Encoding UTF8 %%~f | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 C:%%~pftransform.csv"
        del %%~f
        rename C:%%~pftransform.csv %%~nf.csv
    )
)
```

However, I encountered some file names that contain spaces, e.g. *sample file.csv*
The script above unable to handle these files, is there any workaround for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Put `%%~f` in quotes. Give me a moment to find which question this is a duplicate of...